# How to get rid of extra slash in the generated wadl?

Tags: java, rest, url, cxf

I have an extra slash in wadl that I do not know how to get rid of:

```
<jaxrs:server id="someservice" address="">
mapped REST bean - abc....
```

the Rest endpoint:

`@Path(myPath)
...`

The soapUI project generated based on the wadl points to the url: `localhost/myapp//mypath`. If I make a 'browser' get, on my expected `localhost/myapp/mypath` works!

How can I eliminate the extra /?

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the path you're providing the web service at?  If you've listed your app as being at `myapp/`, what happens if you change that to `myapp`?

Comment: cannot do that! I have a restriction over that....

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix to get rid of the double slash was to edit the Project XML file and change the basePath parameter.  Below is my example.  After reloading the project in SoapUI, everything worked with no more complaints from the server.

OLD Value: `basePath="/jasperserver/rest_v2/"`

NEW Value: `basePath="/jasperserver/rest_v2"`

I saw a similar solution at the [SmartBear community site](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/ReadyAPI-Questions/Ready-API-1-2-Double-slash-in-path/m-p/129380/highlight/true#M31135) that involved replacing all the double slashes in the project file, but this is much simpler.